# Wait for insert in BigQuery in AppsScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm wanting to wait for a BigQuery insert job to complete.  In this use case I'm doing an insert on a CSV file I have in Google Drive, these files can be quite large.

```
var res = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
```

If I had query results, I could poll on the `jobComplete` attribute, but on insert one does not.

Job status state for instance, never seems to be anything other than 'RUNNING'.  **Thus, how does one wait or poll on insert here to ensure completion?**

```
job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
var state = job.status.state;

// this never ends:
for( var sleep=128 ; state.equals('RUNNING') ; sleep*=2 ) {
  Logger.log(state);
  state = job.status.state;
  Utilities.sleep(sleep);
} // for
```

Comment: This is an excerpt from a tutorial `job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
  Logger.log('Load job started. Check on the status of it here: ' +
      'https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', projectId);` The tutorial is found here `https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery` I hope that helps.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help...I've never used BigQuery

Comment: Poll the job status: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobStatus

Comment: @Cooper, the insert() method asynchronously invokes the insert and then returns.  The URL created there is just a user-level link to the console, but does not provide any type of other interface to introspect.

Comment: I got the impression that you could poll that url for status.

Comment: @tehhowch I just updated the question, but effectively the jobstatus.state never seems to change, even though the job does complete on the backend.

Comment: You need to actually query that job again. Use the `jobs#get` endpoint with the job reference you were given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your insert is the same as mine,  However, when I am running an `insert` statement, I still use the `BigQuery.Jobs.query()` command.  That allows me to still poll the jobStatus state.

```
var sql = "Insert something ..etc";
try {
  var sqlJobResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log("Error while running SQL: %s\n Stack: %s",sql, e.stack);
    throw e;
  }
  var jobId = sqlJobResults.jobReference.jobId;

  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  var maxWaitMs = 60000;
  var waitedMs = 0;

  while (!sqlJobResults.jobComplete && waitedMs < maxWaitMs) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    waitedMs += sleepTimeMs;
    sqlJobResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  if (waitedMs >= maxWaitMs) {
    Logger.log('SQL did not return within the time limit);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The job object returned by insert is not dynamic. That's why you need to collect the job id and run this:

```
var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
while (BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobResult.id).status.state != "DONE") Utilities.sleep(1000);
```